# How to get the 'line' in an distance - transfomed image using python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, distance, transformation

I have a semi problem with a project I am working on currently. I have successfully used distance transform (`cv2.distanceTransform`) on an image. Now I need to get the bright 'line' that is within the contour (the place that is the furthest from the contours). I do already have an algorithm that does it but the result has some mistakes that I'd like to fix. Yet I don't know how. I am using python, opencv and PyCharm.

Distance image:

[image]

I tried several forms of thresholding, canny and hough (which doesn't work on curved lines i guess). None work for my needs. 
My current code works like this. I construct an interval where I look for the pixels with the biggest value. The value of these pixels is set to 255. I go through the image twice. Once starting with the rows and once starting with the columns. Sadly doing this like that will come with pixels that do not belong to the line. The reason for this is of course that the used intervals are calculated either row wise or column wise.

The result is:

[image]

As you can see its not a final line through the contour. This image I will later use as a mask to plot a histogram.

```
def maxValueinIntervall(pathname, bounds, rowMax, colMax):
    img = cv2.imread(pathname, 0)
    res = np.zeros(img.shape, img.dtype)
    maxValue = 0
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    for i in range(img.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img.shape[1]):
            if(img[i, j] == bounds and img[i, j + 1] > bounds and img[i, j - 1] <= bounds):
                n = 1
                k = j
                myList = []
                while(img[i, k + n ] > bounds):
                    myList.append(img[i, k + n])
                    k = n + k
                maxValue = max(myList)

            if (maxValue > rowMax and img[i, j] == maxValue):
                res[i, j] = 255

    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        for i in range(img.shape[0]):
            if(img[i, j] == bounds and img[i + 1, j] > bounds and img[i - 1, j] <= bounds):
                n = 1
                k = i
                myList = []
                while(img[k + n, j] > bounds):
                    myList.append(img[k + n, j])
                    k = n + k
                maxValue = max(myList)

            if (maxValue > colMax and img[i, j] == maxValue):
                res[i, j] = 255

    return res
```

Maybe there is already an opencv function that does this that I have not found. I hope to improve my solution, so that I can get a better mask for my next step. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Check if this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095476/is-there-any-build-in-function-can-do-skeletonization-in-opencv

Comment: Thank you! That does help a lot.