# How to measure the length of a curved contour

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Im trying to measure the contour length in pixels of a [curved contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3K3u.png)
.

```
image = cv2.imread('black_white_image.png')
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
cv2.imwrite('cnt_'+file_name, image)
```

Then I calculate the length by calculating the euclidean distance between a pair of pixels as:-

```
euclidean_dist=0
for i in range(len(contours[0])):
    try:
        x=0;
        y=0;
        x=-contours[i][0]+contours[i+1][0]
        y=-contours[i][1]+contours[i+1][1]
        dist+=math.hypot(x,y)
        #print (math.hypot(x,y),contours[i],contours[i+1])
    except:
        continue
print (euclidean_dist)
```

But its printing the length as **289 pixels**, whereas the approx length is **130 pixels** (I manually calculated in inkscape by zooming in the image).
Theres some logical error in calculating the distance which I cant seem to figure out.

Comment: What is the variable `tem`?

Comment: use `cv2.arcLength`

Comment: @RiccardoBucco sorry, just updated the code

Comment: @Miki sorry but arcLength is returning wrong length(had already checked that), if you open the image in any image editor, even by glancing for a while youll know that the length is 130pixels but arcLength is giving 246

Comment: With `findContours` you find the contour (outer boundary) of your white blob, whose length is basically two times of what you expect. You want to compute the length of the skeleton instead. So you can first skeletonize your image (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33098888/5008845) for an example), and then compute it's contour (on skeletonized blobs findContours will retrieve what you expect), and then use arcLength