# Processing image as input for mnist model

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, mnist

I have an image from which I need to detect the number. I have developed a CNN model for the same. But because my image is of a different color format (different from the mnist inputs which are white in black background), I need to process my image appropriately.

[image: input]

This is the input image. I need to convert it into white in black ground so I can pass it through my model to detect the number `3`.

I have tried to remove the border from the image and then invert the color to generate image of the required format.

My code so far :

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_name = 'input.png'
image = cv2.imread(img_name, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
gray = cv2.resize(image, (256,256))
result = gray[40:216, 40:216]
```

So the above code removes the border after resizing the image. This is the image obtained now when I use `cv2.imwrite()`

[image: result]

Then I tried to invert the colors as follows :

```
ans = cv2.bitwise_not(result)
ans1 = (ans//145)*255 # so the only values present are 0 and 255
```

[image: final result - ans1]

This is the final image I have. As `3` is typed out very thick, my model tends to predict it as 8. Any help on how to process the image in a better way would be really helpful. Thanks a lot in advance.

**Edit 1 :**

I would like to remove the borders properly from images. In some cases the image is also being cropped away or the borders are still present when I try it using my code.

More images are present [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/126OraF-n2rGVjGjCCLfkOs-K5OS8Yt4m?usp=sharing)

Comment: You could try thresholding the grayscale image so that your get a thinner character. Also  you could crop a bit better so the bottom of the 3 is not nearly cropped off. Also you could use morphology erode on your white 3 to thin that or do some more proper thinning using morphology.

Comment: Perhaps look at skeletonization: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095476/is-there-any-build-in-function-can-do-skeletonization-in-opencv

Comment: Skeletonization will _convert_ all your characters into a line of 1 pixel width (thick), this may come in handy if you want to "normalize" the thickness of all the blobs.

Comment: @eldesgraciado Yes skeletonization is only half the story.  I'd probably use some dilation to increase the thickness of the strokes a little bit.  Or an even better approach would be to use the distance transform and any pixels beyond a certain percentage away from the largest value produced by the DT would remain.  This would result in a digit that is slightly thicker than the skeletonization version.

Comment: Why do you insist on cutting the edges? Besides a simple erosion after the final step, would make it easier for the detector to distinguish the correct number.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is subtracting each pixel: `(255 - gray)`

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("gHeKR.png")
grey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
inverted = 255 - grey
cv2.imwrite("inverted.png", cv2.resize(inverted, (256, 256)))
```

Result:

[image]

But, the problem may not be solved only by `image-processing`

> But because my image is of a different color format (different from the mnist inputs which are white in black background), I need to process my image appropriately.

The image color format should not be a problem for the convolutional layers.

Assume you are 100% correct on your idea. Then populate images using `keras` image generator. The idea is to populate more samples from the given image, so the classifier learns the correct label.

For instance:

```py
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Total Generated number
total_number = 5

data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255, shear_range=0.2,
                              zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)

# Create image to tensor
img = load_img("3/3.png", grayscale=True)
arr = img_to_array(img)
tensor_image = arr.reshape((1, ) + arr.shape)

for i, _ in enumerate(data_gen.flow(x=tensor_image,
                                 batch_size=1,
                                 save_to_dir="3",
                                 save_prefix="generated",
                                 save_format=".png")):
    if i > total_number:
        break
```

Results:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Of course, you can change the parameters of the `datagen` the idea is sampling image with different parameters, so CNN will label 3 correctly.

***Possible Question1:*** Why I'm not 100% sure about the problem is color format?

---

Answer: Depends on your CNN's accuracy. If your CNN's accuracy is between 99.2% and 99.8% for MNIST, then using the `ImageGenerator` solve your problem.

But, if CNN's accuracy is below 99.2%, well the problem is in your architecture, first you need to reach or pass the threshold accuracy 99.2% on the MNIST.For more check the [website](https://benchmarks.ai/mnist)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is hard limits set at 0 and 255. Avoid the floor division (or instead use a set of logical statements). Utilize division and try various values going upwards from 145. The more upwards you go, the lesser the thickness of 'white' regions in your output.