# how to calculate the thickness of the contour using opencv / how to calculate the width of the objec

Tags: python, opencv

Shown as the image. Firstly I used the cv2.findcontour() method to find the contour of the object, then I want to get the width of the object, so I used the cv2.getEllipse() method to fit the object into a ellipse, and then got the length (red line) and width (orange line) of the image.

However, it's obviously that the width(orange line) is not the width or thickness of the object, the thickness should be the blue line. So, I wonder how to calculate the blue line.

Hopefully someone can help me with it, Thanks~

[image: image1]

Comment: You need a more accurate specification of what you want to measure. Is it the smallest width of the object? The blue line is not smallest width. Is the blue line parallel to the orange line? Then you'd use a totally different algorithm

Answer (score 0):

[Topological skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton) could help you with the task.

You would have to find the skeleton and then 'measure' the distance between the skeleton and the contour in both directions.

[image: Skeleton]

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33095476/4649452) asking for a skeleton implementation.