# Any good OpenCV or SKImage techniques to thin out gridlines?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I have extracted a clean grid pattern:

[image: Grid]

This above is the grid before I "skeletonize" (or thin, or perform the medial axis transform).

An below is the image after an application of `skimage.skeletonize|medial_axis|thin` or `method=lee` for the skeletonize:

[image: Oblated Grid]

These seem to eliminate the grid entirely due to the "boldness" or "thickness" of the lines.

Is there a preferred method to thin out these lines?

Comment: I don't think skeletonize is going to achieve what you are trying to achieve. There is already a question regarding what you are after, check out Miki's answer that uses morphological operations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095476/is-there-any-build-in-function-can-do-skeletonization-in-opencv

Comment: What's your actual desired output, which parts should be deleted, and which should stay? To me, that's not clear. Could you please provide a sketch or similar?

Comment: @HansHirse it should have connectivity and leaf edges exactly like the original image, in the center of the original images apparent edges, of width 1, of the same length, with right angle corners (ideally)

Comment: @Chris Did you try Miki's answer? I think it should produce 1px width lines within the grid.

Comment: @KnightForked I actually have that method implemented here.  It has a similar result to the one pictured above.  I think the distance map version is the optimal version, but that requires identification of the ridges in the distance map... You don't happen to know the trick for that, do you?

Comment: Can you upload your test images sans the plot lines? Also, if you can, please upload the desired output image. Yeah, I just tested Miki's answer and the result is optically far better than the one you posted but it is still not good enough. (Y)

Comment: @Chris I have added a solution that seems to, kind of, work with the one image that you have posted. I thought about finding ridges in the distance map but couldn't come up with a reliable way to do so. If you were able to find a way to do so then please post your solution to help broader SO community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified @Miki's answer (actually my search revealed that it was originally posted by another SO user in 2013). See if this solution is something that you could modify, by maybe tweaking a few parameters, to work for your case.

```
oElem = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(10,1))
h = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, oElem,  iterations = 5)

oElem = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(1,10))
v = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, oElem,  iterations = 5)

size = np.size(img)
skelh = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)
skelv = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)

ret,img = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
done = False
while( not done):
    eroded = cv2.erode(h,element)
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
    temp = cv2.subtract(h,temp)
    skelh = cv2.bitwise_or(skelh,temp)
    h = eroded.copy()
 
    if cv2.countNonZero(h)==0:
        done = True
        
done = False
while( not done):
    eroded = cv2.erode(v,element)
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
    temp = cv2.subtract(v,temp)
    skelv = cv2.bitwise_or(skelv,temp)
    v = eroded.copy()
 
    if cv2.countNonZero(v)==0:
        done = True
        
skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skelh,skelv)
```

[image: Result skeleton image]

Comment: I'll check it out! Yeah, it seems to me that these morph ops are over generalized, and we should have some specialized functions for grids and boxes

Comment: DId it work? I think it should work on most of the similar images. You may have to dilate skelh and skelv a bit due to them getting eroded in the first step. Not quite sure if any specialized function is going to work on all kinds of grids and boxes. Working on distance map would be best bet in that direction but reliably finding ridges would be pretty hard. This solution should work well if the grid/box lines are reasonably aligned horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Not yet -- I'll accept it for now, and ping you on here if I can't reproduce it when I get a chance to run that part of my code